# Taking images in parallel and saving them asynchronously using Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing

This is a more general question regarding concurrency/parallelism, but as I don't have too much experience in those topics I am asking specifically for my use case.

I have two cameras plugged into my PC. I can control them over an SDK (PySpin in my case). I acquire and save the images for `duration` seconds using this simplified loop:

```py
count = 0
t_end = time.time() + duration
while time.time() < t_end:
    for cam in cameras:
        img_raw = cam.GetNextImage()
        img = img_raw.GetNDArray()
        cv2.imwrite('{}_img_{}.png'.format(device_name, count), img)
        img_raw.Release()
        count += 0
```

There are two problems here:

1. The cameras block each other. Let's say the first camera has a high exposure time. The other cameras would need to wait for this camera to take the image.
2. Saving the images is slowing down the process and could theoretically slow down the frame rate of the cameras.

I would like to do following: The cameras should take the images in parallel and images should be saved in whenever an image is taken, i.e. while the camera is already acquiring the next image.

As I said, I am not familiar with concurrency/parallelism and therefore I don't really know how to tackle it. But, I think to solve the first problem I need multi processing/threading (parallelism) for example using `multiprocessing`. But for the second problem I would need an asynchronous process using `asyncio`.

Am I on the right path? If so, how could I implement this?

Comment: Are you recording photos continuously for months/years, or is it a relatively short experiment? Have you timed how long it takes each camera to acquire an image? Have you timed how long if takes to save an image? Have you considered saving as JPEG which is normally faster than PNG? How big is each image in pixels? Are they colour or greyscale images? Have you considered saving as video rather than stills? Are the two cameras independent or does there have to be some synchronisation between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be late to this, but I'm developing a Python package that lets you do just this. It's still very much under development, but check it out if you're interested:

https://github.com/jbhunt/parallel-pyspin

The TLDR is each camera runs on it's own process (via multiprocessing). There are classes which handle all of the nittty gritty of setting up a primary and secondary cameras. All you need to know are the cameras' serial numbers plus you have to follow these instructions for setting up the physical trigger:

https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/configuring-synchronized-capture-with-multiple-cameras

Feel free to contribute :)

Comment: That's fantastic. I don't have a trigger. Does it work without one, just taking x FPS in parallel?

Comment: The VideoStream class might be of interest to you. It works almost exactly like OpenCV’s VideoCapture class. In short, it starts a child process that is constantly checking the camera for a new image. When a new image is detected, it saves the image as a process-safe array as a class attribute which can be read out as a numpy array with the ‘read’ method. There’s more documentation in the README if you wanna check it out. Also, Just out of curiosity, would it be useful to have the ability to start video acquisition via a software trigger at the cost of synchronous acquisition between cameras?

Answer (score 2):

Very generic advice without any code but it might be worth a try:

suggestion to implement three threads

Thread 1:
captures raw images from camera 1 and adds a tuple of `(raw_image, filename_to_save_as)`  to a thread safe queue (`from queue import Queue`)

Thread 2:
captures raw images from camera 2 and adds a tuple of `(raw_image, filename_to_save_as)`  to a thread safe queue (`from queue import Queue`)

Thread 3: processes the queue and saves each raw image under the passed filename.

**Please note:** You might want to add a max size to the queue to avoid memory overflows in case wrting the files is really the bottle neck in your setup